# Unable to push pre-trained model from Google colab to Huggingface for hosting Bot

Tags: git, google-colaboratory, pre-trained-model, huggingface-tokenizers

I have trained a Chatbot model in Google collab and when pushing to Huggingface, it doesn't push and the notebook keeps executing and doesn't push, the size is around 500MB

```
!sudo apt-get install git-lfs
```

```
!git config --global user.email "MY EMAIL"
!git config --global user.name "MY name"
```

```
model    .push_to_hub('MODEL REPO NAME', use_auth_token='API TOKEN')
tokenizer.push_to_hub('MODEL REPO NAME', use_auth_token='API TOKEN')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation on Google Colaboratory's part.

You can git clone via your API key as the password, [which can be accessed here.](https://huggingface.co/settings/token)

Another step, if using colab, you must also declare your email:

`!git config --global user.email "email@example.com"`

Then clone with api key:

`!git clone https://USERNAME:APIKEY@huggingface.co/user/repo`

Alternatively, use your huggingface login credentials:

`!git clone https://username:password@huggingface.co/user/repo`